# SQL get unique combinations of a field

Tags: sql

I have a table called T1 as below:

```
id value
1 C
2 B
3 A
```

How can I find all the pairs of value, one pair for each unique combination(order does not matter), ordered by the values in the pair? Expected output below:

```
A B
A C
B C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self cross join:

```
select distinct t1.value value1, t2.value value2
from tablename t1 cross join tablename t2
where t1.value < t2.value
```

Comment: There's no need for DISTINCT in that query using the example dataset...

Comment: If the table contains duplicates then DISTINCT is needed there. If not it can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

All permutations is a CROSS JOIN, all combinations of two items is just a CROSS JOIN but filtered (so, an INNER JOIN) such that the first item is lower than the second...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   T1    AS Ta
INNER JOIN
   T1    AS Tb
      ON Tb.value > Ta.value
ORDER BY
   Ta.value,
   Tb.value
```